# Parallelization of multiple operations and concatenation of results

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, task-parallel-library

I'd like to implement the following in a **Silverlight 5.0** application using Task Parallel Library (SL5 has Task factories but no Parallel.For). I have plenty of threading knowledge but none on TPL so this seems a good task to get some :)

Currently I have some code, which executes synchronously as follows:

```
public interface IProcessor
{
    IEnumerable<Bar> Provide(Foo param)
}

private IEnumerable<IProcessor> processors; 

public void DoMultiOperations(Foo param, Action<IEnumerable<Bar>> callback)
{
    List<Bar> allResults = new List<Bar>();

    foreach(var processor in this.processors)
    {
        allResults.AddRange(processor.Provide(param));
    }

    callback(allResults);
}
```

Consider each `IProcessor` accepts a `Foo` parameter to `Provide` returning an `IEnumerable<Bar>`. The aggregation of all results are sent back to the caller via the callback.

Now some of the IProcessors execute immediately. Some make a call to a server and can take several seconds. I would like to schedule N tasks for N `IProcessor` instances and when all are complete (or time-out) concatenate the `IEnumerable<Bar>` results.

If possible I'd like to add a timeout to the overall operation so if all don't complete within 15 seconds, throw.

Your help much appreciated :)

Comment: How can they be asynchronous when `IProcessor` is clearly a synchronous interface?

Comment: Sorry, just refactored the interface to IProcessor to be synchronous (to block). I will re-word the question

Answer (score 4):

Again I can't test this code but it should work if Silverlight doesn't have Parallel.ForEach you can you use Task.WaitAll

```
    private IEnumerable<IProcessor> processors;

    public void DoMultiOperations(Foo param, Action<IEnumerable<Bar>> callback)
    {
        var allResults = new ConcurrentQueue<Bar>();
        Task.WaitAll(processors.Select(processor => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetData(processor, param, allResults))).ToArray());
        callback(allResults);
    }

    private static void GetData(IProcessor processor, Foo param, ConcurrentQueue<Bar> allResults)
    {
        var enumerable = processor.Provide(param);
        foreach (var bar in enumerable)
        {
            allResults.Enqueue(bar);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ach, its silverlight so no Parallel.ForEach. Still +1 for effort :)

Comment: With this code, the results from each processor could be interleaved. That may or may not be a problem.

Comment: @svick I need to do some ordering anyway, that's not a problem. What is, is that Parallel.ForEach isn't available in silverlight 5. You can create Tasks though :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is roughly correct

```
public void DoMultiOperations(Foo param, Action<IEnumerable<Bar>> callback)
{
    var allResults = new List<Bar>();

    // We are using all the default options on the TaskFactory 
    // except when we are appending the results this has to be synchronized 
    // as List<> is not multithreading safe (a more appropriate collection perhaps) 
    var taskFactory = new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<Bar>>(
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

    // Kick off a task for every processor
    var tasks =
        new List<Task<IEnumerable<Bar>>>(processors.Count());
    tasks.AddRange(
        processors.Select(
            processor =>
            taskFactory.StartNew(() => processor.Provide(param))));

    if (Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), 5 * 1000))
    {
        foreach (Task<IEnumerable<Bar>> task in tasks)
        {
            allResults.AddRange(task.Result);
        }
        callback(allResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: @sll no, the return type of .StartNew() is a Task<TResult> (largely returned instantly).  The Task are started off asynchronously.

Comment: Only one problem which disregard nice `ContinueWith` - this is dangerous using the same instance of List in multiple async operations, so you've to extend anonymous method in `ContinueWith` or use one of the concerrent collections which has no `AddRange`

Answer (score 1):

This would run all tasks in parallel asynchronously:

```
public void DoMultiOperations(Foo param, Action<IEnumerable<Bar>> callback)
{
    // since each task's callback would access this storage - we are using
    // one of the concurrent queue
    ConcurrentQueue<Bar> allResults = new ConcurrentQueue<Bar>();

    Task[] tasks = this.processors.Select(p => new Task(() =>
        {
            IEnumerable<Bar> results = p.Provide(param);
            foreach (var newItem in results)
            {
                allResults.Enqueue(newItem);
            }
        })).ToArray();

    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        task.Start();
    }

    // 5 seconds to wait or inject a value into this method
    Task.WaitAll(tasks, 5000);                
    callback(allResults);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like the following

```
// Allow for cancellation.
CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken();
TaskCreationOptions atp = TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent; 

List<Bar> allResults = new List<Bar>();
Task<List<Bar>> asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Bar>>(() => asyncMethod(token, atp), token);

// Continuation is returned when the asyncMethod is complete.
asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // Handle the result.
    switch (task.Status)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            break;
        case TaskStatus.Canceled:
            break;
        case TaskStatus.Faulted:
    }
}
```

In your `asyncMethod` you could do something like the following

```
private List<Bar> asyncMethod(CancellationToken token)
{
    List<Bar> allResults = new List<Bar>();

    foreach(var processor in this.processors)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<Bar>>(() => 
        {     
            processor.Provide(param);
        }, atp).ContinueWith( cont => { allResults.AddRange(cont.Result) }); 

        // Cancellation requested from UI Thread.
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    return allResults;
}
```

Yo can then get the overall result (a `List<Bar>`) from the continuation called `task` in the first snippet. You call the cancellation through some event through the UI like

```
// Cancellation requested from UI Thread.
if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

I could not test this, but something like the above should work. Please see this [great introduction to TPL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n) for more information and use of the class...

I do hope this is of use.

Answer (score 0):

With TPL you can pass the loop state to inform the other threads to abort in the case of a timeout.  You need to do something like:

```
    public void DoMultiOperations(Foo param, Action<IEnumerable<Bar>> callback)
    {
        ConcurrentBag<Bar> allResults = new ConcurrentBag<Bar>();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        Parallel.ForEach(this.processors, (processor, loopState) =>
        {
            foreach (Bar item in processor.Provide(param))
            {
                allResults.Add(item);
            }

            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 15000)
            {
                loopState.Stop();
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }
        });

        callback(allResults);
    }
```